# Detecting Item visibility in a VirtualizingStackPanel for lazy loading images

Tags: windows-store-apps, virtualizingstackpanel

Here is my scenario:

I have a Gridview that shows data retrieved from a network service. The number of data may be quite large. So, the VirtualizingStackPanel is used to display the content. Some of those data may require retrival of images when they are rendered(lazy loading)

My (very limited) understanding is that the VirtualStackPanel will automatically request data as the grid requiring that data is being rendered. If the element that needs to be rendered is of image type, I send a placeholder image and submit an async network call to retrieve that image.

But, I notice that the calls to render all the element is being received and consequently a deluge of network calls to retrieve images are sent (esp if most of the items are of image type).

Question: Is there something I should be configuring in code (XAML or C#) for the VirtualizingStackPanel or should go the route of detecting if the item is really being displayed and then issue network call?

Here is my XAML.

```
    <GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="3"
        Padding="116,137,40,46"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CellStyleSelector}"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false">

        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>                        
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Here is the Item's Property  which is bound to the Image in XAML

```
    private ImageSource _image = null;
    private String _imagePath = null;
    public ImageSource ThumbImage
    {
        get
        {
            // Check if the image is already cached
            if (this._image == null)
            {

                // Setup a placehoder image
                this._imagePath = "Assets/metro_photo_55@2x.png";                
                this._image = new BitmapImage(new Uri(Defs.BaseUri, this._imagePath));    

                // Async call to download thumb image from server
                this.getThumb();

            }

            return this._image;
        }
        private set 
        {
            this.SetProperty(ref this._image, value);
        }
     }
```

Here is the async call to download the thumb

```
private async void getThumb()
{
   // Get image and store
   Network network = new Network();

   // Since this is a bound property. this action updates the UI
   this.ThumbImage = await network.getImage(this._rawData[Defs.PATH_KEY], true);

   Debug.WriteLine(this._rawData[Defs.PATH_KEY] + " - Thumb retrieved!");

}
```

Comment: Are you doing the lazy loading in your Model? If you are, then that is where the images are being requested from. What you should do is only start the lazy loading process when the image data property is requested (that is, if the property hasn't already been loaded).

Comment: Yes. I do call the lazy load when the bound Image getter is called. But I notice that the getter for the Image is getting called for all of the items.

Comment: Hmmm... Without a bit more code from your model, it will be difficult to help much. There are a couple places it could be happening, but that's the most likely place. One thing you can do that would be helpful is to put a break point in the getter and then traverse the stack trace to see what is calling it in the first place. You may have to continue through the first few in order to find one that should not be called, based on your criteria.

Comment: @Nate Thank you. I have added additional code in the post. Does that make sense?

Comment: Looks like virtualization can be broken in a bunch of cases  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/17385f7d-aadc-4edc-bbff-8738a2f0c917/problem-with-gridview-virtualization-in-vs-for-consumer-preview

Comment: It looks like the VirtualizingStackPanel is not working in the Grouped Items View.

Comment: Ahhhh, indeed. It does not virtualize items of a group, only the group itself. So if you have two large groups, each with half of the items in them, it's likely that an entire half will get loaded.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780657.aspx
That link states taht UI Virtualization is not supported for grouped data..

Comment: Yeah, you have to create your own for it. The other option is to put the groups and the items in the same collection and then use Styles to make them look similar. It's not easy, but it works.